# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {x^b}{e^{ax}}.$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I would like to determine
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {x^b}{e^{ax}}.
$$

I know for sure that the limit when $x$ approaches infinity is $0.$ But what is the $x$ that's in the power of $e$ is in the power of something different than $1$?

Comment: $x \to \infty$, so the denominator grows exponentially larger than the numerator.  Try plugging in some values as x increases. Say, x=1, x=5, x=25, x=100... the fraction gets smaller and smaller rather quickly, even if $b\gt a$.

Comment: $\frac{x^b}{e^{ax}}=\left( \frac{x}{e^{\frac{a}{b}x}} \right)^b$

Comment: Depends on the sign of $a$.

Comment: Either you have more data and you need to write it down, or else you'll have to do cases. For example, if $\;a\le0\,,\,\,b>0\;$ the limit is $\;\infty\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a,b,c$ are positive integers.
I guess what you mean is to evaluate the limit 
$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^c}{e^{ax^b}}$\

Note that this is a limit of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, we can use the L'hosiptal rule.\

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^c}{e^{ax^b}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^{c-b+1}}{abe^{ax^b}}=...$\

Keep doing this, the power in the numerator will become negative and 
hence the limit will be 0

Answer (score 0):

An idea for you:

$$x^b=e^{b\log x}\implies \frac{x^b}{e^{ax}}=e^{b\log x-ax}$$

Let us now check what happens with $\;b\log x-ax\;$  For example, *first case*:

$$a=b=0\implies b\log x-ax=0\implies \;\text{the expression and the limit is}\;\;1$$

Second case:

$$a,b>0\implies b\log x-ax\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}-\infty\implies \text{ the limit is zero}$$

Continue as above with different cases. Remember: $\;x\to\infty\;$ was faster than $\;\log x\to\infty\;$ when $\;x\to\infty\;$